# Create encrypted home after Ubuntu LTS 22.04 installation

Tags: 22.04, encryption, home-directory

I would like to create an encrypted home directory for my users on already installed ubuntu. What is the best way to do this ?

Kind regards,

Sylvain

Comment: You may my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1364413/907096) useful.